# Simplest way to trigger PHP shutdown

Tags: php, error-handling

Is there a simple way to trigger PHP shutdown so that `error_get_last` function returns a real error from within a function registered with `register_shutdown_function`. I need it to test my custom error handling and mailing functions under stress conditions.

Comment: Division by 0 perhaps? :)

Comment: @deceze It's not FORTRAN :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

function shutdown()
{
    echo "shutdown:\n";
    print_r(error_get_last());
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

throw new Exception("fatal error");

print("END")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
trigger_error("You goin' down!", E_USER_ERROR);
```